# Как выполнить последовательность команд cmd из WindowsForm?

Tags: c#, cmd

Как запустить cmd в скрытом режиме из приложения WindowsForm, и выполнять в ней команды с получением ответа.
Или как запустить консольное приложение с атрибутами из WindowsForm, и выполнять в ней команды с получением ответа.

Пример: Запустилась cmd
выполнилась 1 команда
получил ответ
если в ответе 1 то
выполняем команду 2
и тд…

Comment: В google можно найте много примеров того, как это сделать, например попробуйте [это](http://windowsapptutorials.com/tips/general-tips/how-to-execute-a-command-in-c-sharp/). Если что-то не понятно - пишите.

Comment: Одну команду выполнить и получить ответ могу, но как выполнить несколько команд в одной cmd?

Comment: _Одну команду выполнить и получить ответ могу_ - как вы это делаете? Приведите код в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

cmd.exe принимает команды через свой стандартный ввод, а результат выдает в стандартный вывод. Соответственно, нужно перенаправить эти потоки при создании процесса:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Process process;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);            
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived; //подписываемся на событие появления новых данных
        process.Start();            
        process.BeginOutputReadLine(); //начинаем операции асинхронного чтения Output
    }

    private void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {            
        //при получении данных из Output, выведем в TextBox 
        Invoke(new Action(() => { textBox1.Text += e.Data + Environment.NewLine; }));            
    }

    void SendCommand(string cmd)
    {
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd);
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendCommand("program.exe arg1 arg2");
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.Close();
    }
}
```