# Командна в командной строке не работает

Tags: c#

Набираю в командной строке `net use` - показывает все сетевые диски.В моем c# коде - пусто. Не пойму в чем проблема

```
var p = new Process();
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c net use");

processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: наверное потому, что это `"/c net use"` у вас параметры запуска exe файла, а не команда, напечатанная в консоль.

Comment: ну или я сам что то путаю, никогда не запускал консоль кодом. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469790/312041) вроде что то есть

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится. Все показывает. Но, возможно вы натыкаетесь на какую-то проблему с синхронным чтением - ReadToEnd не возвращает, пока буфер не заполнился ну нужную длину, или что-то в этом роде. Попробуйте асинхронное, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977121/Как-выполнить-последовательность-команд-cmd-из-windowsform