# Передача команд в process

Tags: c#

Как я могу работать с процессом? Я могу прочесть результат передаваемого параметра с помощью `StandardOutput` А как мне передать в процесс когда он уже вызван? К примеру передать команду dir в cmd?

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
...
process.Start();
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# - Симуляция ввода текста пользователем в консольное приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909307/c-%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Какой тип приложения?

Comment: Вот это вроде лучше дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/977121/240512